# Getting errors while using token.morph in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, morphological-analysis

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
print("Pipeline:", nlp.pipe_names)
doc = nlp("I was reading the paper.")
token = doc[2] 
print(token.morph)
print(token.morph.get("PronType"))
```

TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type list)

Giving above error for token.morph

Comment: Spacy 3.0.1 returns `[]`. `print(token.morph)` shows `spect=Prog|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Part`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test using Spacy 3.0:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
print("Pipeline:", nlp.pipe_names)
# => Pipeline: ['transformer', 'tagger', 'parser', 'ner', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer']
doc = nlp("I was reading the paper.")
token = doc[2]
print(token.morph)
# => Aspect=Prog|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Part
```

Then, there is no `PronType` attribute here, so printing what you want yields an empty array:

```py
print(token.morph.get("PronType"))
# => []
```